# How do I refer in a kml script within a ballon-text or a description-text to the text from another ballon or description part?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

I have a KML-script with some placemarks which have some content written in the "description" part (in HTML-style). Everything works fine, but in some description-parts I want to include a link/reference that points to the description-part of another placemark within the KML-script.

When the user clicks on a placemark that points to Paris, a ballon with the description content opens (this already works fine). What I want to achieve is that within this ballon the user should be able to click on a highlighted word, e.g. "let's move to Marseille", and after doing so the Paris-Ballon should close while the Marseille-Ballon - which belongs to the description-part of the Marseille-placemark - should open.

Is that possible? I couldn't find anything about that in the documentation or with googling. (Or I'm just too stupid to find it).

Cheers, Emma

Comment: Is this in Google Maps? Or only in Google Earth? Or both?

Comment: KML can be used in both.

Comment: Yes, but Google Maps only supports a subset of KML, and the specific target will determine your options.

Comment: Ah ok. It will be used in Google Earth when its finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link from one Placemark to another using special links in the description where one references the other. The mechanism is called a feature anchor in the KML standard.

Note the URL in Paris placemark is `#marseille;balloonFlyto` where the "id" attribute of the target Placemark is "marseille" and the target action to take when clicked is "balloonFlyto".

Here is complete KML with one placemark linking to another:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>feature anchor</name>
    <description>Feature anchor using ; to delimit action.</description>

    <Placemark id="paris">
      <name>Paris</name>
        <description>
        <![CDATA[ 
        let's move to <a href="#marseille;balloonFlyto">Marseille</a>
      ]]>
      </description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>2.3508,48.8567</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>

    <Placemark id="marseille">
      <name>Marseille</name>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[ 
        Welcome to Marseille.
        Return to <a href="#paris;balloonFlyto">Paris</a>       
      ]]>
      </description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>5.37,43.2964</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>

      </Document>
</kml>
```

The target href in the popup description balloon can be a fragment URL (that is, a URL with a # sign followed by a KML identifier). You can also append an action to the URL with a semi-colon (;) and one of these qualifiers:

- flyto (default) - fly to the Feature
- balloon - open the Feature's balloon but do not fly to the Feature
- balloonFlyto - open the Feature's balloon and fly to the Feature

*Excerpt above from [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#feature).*

Comment: That's what I've been looking for! Thanks a lot!